# Battery Cost of an HTTP request?

Tags: android, sockets, http, google-cloud-messaging

I want to develop an app that requires near real-time communication. For efficiency and feasibility , I found that these technologies are usually used :

1. GCM (google keeps a socket open for messaging, and the developer's server sends messages to google's server, which then 'pushes' that message to the device)
2. Persistent socket- A socket, connected to developer's server is connected forever. whenever there is anything to be pushed, the server pushes it to the device.
3. Long polling- usually an HTTP request, but the server waits for any new message. If there is something new arrives, the server responds.

I would like to know what the battery cost for a send-to-sync message. In this architecture, a persistent socket ( usually GCM) , tells the device to 'check' for anything new from the server, ONLY when there IS something new to be checked. Then the device just polls for the new content.

My app will not have more than a 2to3 (maximum case) messages delivered to the client. So, is it a feasible thing to do ?

Could anybody tell me the approximate 'cost' of one http request ?

Comment: How long is a piece of string?  Seriously though, you didn't state how often these requests are made, how much data is being sent, how the data is being generated, how large the battery is, how efficient the device is, whether it's using wifi or data.

Comment: Note that persistent sockets sometimes don't work as expected. If there is no data transmitted for some minutes the connection may be silently dropped by some network components. In the end you have an open connection where you can send data but the data never reaches the destination. Therefore you have to send some idle data to keep the connection open.

Comment: @Matthew , I mention that the peak can reach up to 2 to 3 requests in one second. but realistically , it would be something like 20 to 30 requests in 24 hours. Also , the size of a string will be no more than a few KB's . Though sometimes, large files like photos may be transferred.

Comment: @Robert, I believe , sending 'heartbeat' signals should prevent the problem you mentioned ?

Comment: Your question can not be answered. "percentage of battery" depends on the battery size. Even reformulating the question to "how many Milliwatt" would not help as power consumption of the CPU depends on the type and technology.

Comment: I did not ask the percentage of the battery(sorry, im changing that ) . I asked the approximate cost of an http request. I would like to know if doing something like this will be a huge impact on battery or not, in realistic conditions.

Comment: The advantage of something like GCM is that the implementation is designed to allow the device's processor to sleep, and be woken up by the power-optimized capabilities built into the mobile network radio, much as if you received a phone call or SMS.  Most of the other mechanisms won't do that, so even apart from the power cost of network operations, you can end up having to keep the processor active.

Comment: btw size of messages from GCM are limited..

> The payload the message contains can be up to 4kb
(http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#payload)

Comment: yes, i am aware of that, thank you